# Why do I not need to include main.cpp?

Tags: c++, program-entry-point

In the small example needsExtern.cpp needs the definition of `global::bar`. needsExtern.cpp would normally include the file with the definition (in this case main.cpp). However, since the file is main.cpp it is not needed.

Why does needsExtern.cpp not need to include main.cpp?

needsExtern.h

```
struct NeedsExtern
{
    NeedsExtern();
};
```

needsExtern.cpp

```
#include "needsExtern.h"
#include <iostream>

namespace global
{
    extern const int bar;
}

NeedsExtern::NeedsExtern()
{
    std::cout << global::bar << "\n";
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "needsExtern.h"

namespace global
{
    extern const int bar{26};
}

void main()
{
    NeedsExtern ne;
}
```

Comment: The `extern` keyword, when applied to a declaration, means "defined externally." Since it appears you are linking this into a single image, the linker is able to resolve `extern const int bar` to the one in `main.o`.

Comment: *Why does needsExtern.cpp not need to include main.cpp?* What makes you think that? The answer is, "it doesn't."

Comment: That's like asking "Why does main.cpp not need to include needsExtern.cpp?"

Comment: I'll edit my example to try and make this clear. I will define another extern variable called foo in anotherExtern.h. needsExtern.cpp will have to include anotherExtern.h to access it.

Comment: anotherExtern.h makes a poor header file, since you will have a multiple definition problem if two source files include it.

Comment: I see that now. I will remove my edits as they aren't helpful.

Comment: `main` returns `int`, not `void`, bud.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is precisely where `extern` is invented for: the compiler just *assumes* the variable is defined elsewhere in the project. You can read more about this principle [here](http://mylinuxbook.com/the-concept-of-extern-variables-in-c/).